# Derivative of $5^{2 x+1}$

Tags: calculus

Im am trying to find $y'$ of y=$5^{2 x+1}$

The answer is given as:

$$2 \text{Ln}(5) 5^{2 x+1}$$

I get $2 \text{Ln}(5)$, what am I missing, could someone take me through step by step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$5^{2x+1} = (e^{\ln(5)})^{2x+1} = e^{(2x+1)\ln(5)}$$
Differentiating, we obtain
$$2\ln(5)e^{(2x+1)\ln(5)} = 2\ln(5) \cdot 5^{2x+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

$y=5^{2x+1}$.

Then $\ln y=(2x+1)\ln 5$.

So, $y'/y=2\ln 5$ and hence $y'=y\cdot 2\ln 5=2(\ln 5)5^{2x+1}$

Comment: Good old logarithmic differentiation!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go through the ln property manipulations you can use this crib sheet. 
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Calculus_Cheat_Sheet_All.pdf

On page three it shows (a<sup>x</sup>)' = a<sup>x</sup> ln(a)

We can understand this to mean

(a<sup>u</sup>)' = a<sup>u</sup> ln(a) du

for situations where u' isn't 1. For 
u = 2x+1, the situation you have, du = 2. Thus

a<sup>u</sup> ln(a) du = 5<sup>2x+1</sup> ln(5) (2)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[5^{2x+1}\right]=\frac{d}{dx} \left[e^{\ln 5^{2x+1}}\right] =\frac{d}{dx} \left[e^{(2x+1)\ln 5}\right]
$$
$$
=e^{(2x+1)\ln 5}\frac{d}{dx}[(2x+1)\ln 5]=5^{2x+1}(2\ln 5)
$$